# Display footer in recyclerview with livedata

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a pagedlistAdapter added  in recyclerview.how to display loader at the bottom to load more data

Answer (score 0):

You have add last item as processBar in your recycleview.
link-http://www.devexchanges.info/2017/02/android-recyclerview-dynamically-load.html

Comment: How to add null in a livelist